# Confusion about computing the Jordan Canonical form.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on part c of the first problem of [this released exam.](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/F08_Final_Exam-C.Zickert.pdf)

> Calculate the Jordan Canonical form of:
>   \begin{bmatrix}
>  0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & -2 & 1 \\
>  -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & -1 \\
> \end{bmatrix}

To calculate the Jordan Canonical form I am following [this guide](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~jlindquist/115B/JCF.pdf).

From part b $\dim(N(A+I)) = 1$ and $\dim(N((A+I)^2)) = 2$ Hence, according to the guide above I should be able to conclude that $\dim(N(A+I)^3)) = 3$ because $\dim(N(A+I)^n)$ is strictly increasing until it surpases the number of the multiplicity of the eigenvalue. (Which in this case we have $\lambda = -1$ with a multiplicity of $3$.

From the guid above I am lead to believe we should take $d_1 = 1$, $d_2 = 2$, and $d_3 = 3$.

So:

$$d_1 = 1$$
$$d_2 - d_1 = 1$$
$$d_3 - d_2 = 1$$

I then conclude that there is is on block of size $1$, one of size $2$ and one of size $3$. Which doesn't add up to me. My question is: How am I misreading the guide I linked to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should conclude that there is one block of size **at least** 1, one block of size **at least** 2, and one block of size **at least** 3.

Of course, this means that there is only one block, and it has size 3.

Comment: Oh. Silly mistake on my part the example made it appear as if you should have at least 1 size on block etc. Thanks!